# How to write a auto adaptive panel like this in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

As the pictures shown, I have the original picture, and want to add some texts.
I tried grid, but not perfect. When the window size changed or on pc/mobile, I want they all be in the right place.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Who are we" Margin="5"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxJobs" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="600" MaxHeight="900">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/WhoAreWe.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/WhoAreWe.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>-->
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Who are we？" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Programmers！" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="What we do？" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Fix Bugs！" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Then what？" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Write new Bugs！" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the question, the job seems like for `VisualStates` with `Adaptive Triggers`.

I went through your code and I must say, ideally your XAML must not look like that, there are better ways to implement the same kind of UI in a way that'll help keep things dynamic and extensible. As per the current code snippet you shared, it seems you'll have a hard time changing/adding more fields to your UI (currently it's just 6 but what happens when it becomes 15, would you still add 8 rows then?).

Leaving this aside, I've tweaked around with your code:

1. used a common `style` for the `textbox` so that tomorrow if you want to change the textbox styles, you just need to do it once.
2. Used a `RelativePanel` instead of a `rootGrid` which reduces the row and column definitions and hence adds more maintainability.
3. Modified `Row` and `Column` definitions to `Auto` from `*` to provide adaptive UI.
4. Put your `Image` elements in a `ViewBox` to provide fluidity when window size changes.
5. And finally added `visualStates` to handle the visibility of the `textbox`.

The Updated Code is as below:

```
<RelativePanel Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Compressed">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox1.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox2.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox3.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox4.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox5.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBox.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox1.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox2.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox3.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox4.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="textBox5.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <TextBlock Name="headerText" Text="Who are we?" FontSize="18" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="10,5"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxJobs" Margin="10,5" BorderThickness="1" RelativePanel.Below="headerText" MinWidth="200"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="600" MaxHeight="900" MinHeight="300" RelativePanel.Below="comboboxJobs" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"  Background="Gray" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CollapsableA" Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CollapsableB" Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CollapsableC" Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Who are we？" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy1.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Programmers！" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy2.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="What we do？" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy3.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Fix Bugs！" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy4.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Then what？" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy5.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Write new Bugs！" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image Source="Assets/Dummy6.jpg"/>
        </Viewbox>

    </Grid>
</RelativePanel>
```

And in your `<Page.Resources>` add the style for the `textbox`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextboxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

---

### Recommendations

It's not advisable to keep your UI so strictly defined in a dynamic workflow and considering the `combobox`,

I get a feeling that the lower images are all based on what the user has selected in the `combobox`.

This feels like a job for a `GridView` of which the `ItemSource` is `binded` to an `observableCollection<MyUIClass>` and the the `MyUIClass` has two properties such as `Text` and `ImagePath` and you can easily populate the `Collection` and `RaisePropertyChanged` using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your UI now is completely dynamic.

**Please Note:** The concepts of `DataBinding` would save you a lot of time and effort. Also `MVVM` would help a lot but `MVVM` wouldn't be a show stopper

Comment: Hi, Aditya. Thanks for your help. You use 6 images to fill each grid. This is a good way. At first, I only use one large image as background. So it is hard to locate the textboxs.

Comment: No a problem. Glad could help